# Calendar react component - Marking a week when selecting a day

Tags: reactjs, calendar

I am wondering if there is a calendar component that will allow me to mark a whole week as selected (like the date range) when I am selecting a day?

The idea is to get a range from the start of the week to the end of the week when a user selected a day in the calendar and mark it in the calendar.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

it's easy to accomplish using http://momentjs.com/

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import moment from 'moment'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      date: moment()
    };
  }
  handleDateChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({date: e.target.value}, ()=>{
      console.log(moment(this.state.date).startOf('week').toISOString()); //week start date
      console.log(moment(this.state.date).endOf('week').toISOString()) //week end date
    })

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input 
          type="date" 
          value={this.state.date} 
          onChange={this.handleDateChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Check it out here (make sure to open console) https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kfhmva

You get 2 dates: start, end of week. You can use it in any daterange picker and mark range as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There was a great package you can check here https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates

I has different Options can be checked here http://airbnb.io/react-dates/